# cURL simultaneous Requests: Ending Up with error(7) - CURLE_COUDN'T_CONNECT

Tags: php, curl

My Website Use `Zebra_cURL` to get request parallel request.But when the reaching about 500 request System starts to return `CURLE_COUDN'T_CONNECT` error.I have read some answers from Forums too.I tried some of them.But no fix.Please Give a quick answer if someone knows a solution for this error.
I am currently Using This code. Assume that `$com_url_arr_glo` Array has been defined already and it contains about 2300 urls..

```
$curl1 = new Zebra_cURL();

            $curl1->cache('cache', 3600);
            $curl1->option(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
            $curl1->option(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $curl1->ssl(true);

            $curl1->get($com_url_arr_glo, 'getsizemk');
```

`getsizemk` is a **function** To get some information inside each url after scraping is over for each URL.This is as mentioned in [Zebra cURL Documentation](https://stefangabos.github.io/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL.html#methodssl).

This is the complete Array I get from Zebra_cURL after the error

```
[info] => Array
    (
        [original_url] => https://www.masterkreatif.com/page/12
        [url] => https://www.masterkreatif.com/page/12
        [content_type] => 
        [http_code] => 0
        [header_size] => 0
        [request_size] => 162
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 30.109
        [namelookup_time] => 1.0E-6
        [connect_time] => 0.406
        [pretransfer_time] => 0.906
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 0
        [speed_download] => 0
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => -1
        [upload_content_length] => -1
        [starttransfer_time] => 0
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [redirect_url] => 
        [primary_ip] => 104.24.117.230
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_port] => 443
        [local_ip] => 192.168.43.56
        [local_port] => 25775
    )

[headers] => Array
    (
        [last_request] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Request Method] => GET /page/12 HTTP/1.1
                        [Host] => www.masterkreatif.com
                        [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0)
                        [Accept] => */*
                        [Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate
                    )

            )

        [responses] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[body] => 
[response] => Array
    (
        [0] => CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT
        [1] => 28
    )
```

**Also Forgot to say,** URL Is working very FINE!

**Guys!I found a Solution.**
But don't know this is applicable for all types of this error.But all I did Is just adding a 5 second delay Between all the processed 30 URL pack. It fixed this error anyway. Thanks Guys for all the comments!
All I added is this

```
$curl->pause_interval = 5;
$curl->threads = 30;
```

(Those are for Zebra_cURL)

Comment: Can you share the verbose output? (`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`)

Comment: See some old threads. Knowing versions (libcurl) would also help.

Comment: I had a similar issue before, it's possible the server is seeing your 500 requests as a port scan attack and temporarily stops responding to you. Try adding a delay.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher Yeah,It will get fixed but, Delaying is going to make the system bit slower.All I need Is speed.Is there a method to stop it in the server.

Comment: Is it a problem with the User Agent? Should I try changing it?

Comment: @TheBangBandit there is a way, but only if you own the target server in question.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher Yeah, I am Running the script on a localserver. But,My real website's server is a shared server. As the results are inserted into a database, I can transfer it to my website's server. Answer Is yeah! kind of! What's that method

Comment: @HarveyFletcher Thanks Buddy. I could have asked what you said before. As I found that that delay happens only between a pack of URLs I tried it.IT WORKED!

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in titles here. If you found your own answer you can post and accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may be seeing your high number of requests as an attack and just refusing to serve you.

The quick fix is to add a short delay between making each request.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thanks for marking my answer as solved.